# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at account/signup/

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Can someone please help me? I created a sign up form under:

```
blog/templates/regitsration/singup.html  # This is the template
blog/templates/regitsration/login.html
blog/templates/blog/***
blog/views.py
blog/urls.py
blog/forms.py
```

**views**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

The site isn't working correctly. It says:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at accounts/signup/
registration/signup.html
```

The files are at 
https://github.com/VictorLeRed1275/my-first-blog and
https://victorlered.pythonanywhere.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your template [`singup.html`](https://github.com/VictorLeRed1275/my-first-blog/blob/master/blog/templates/registration/singup.html). It should be `signup.html`.